# Using more than one network in Hardhat script

Tags: hardhat, polygon

I need to work with the [Tokemak](https://www.tokemak.xyz/) protocol, and some part of the project I'm developing needs to extract information from [this](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x7A9A3395afB32F923a142dBC56467Ae5675Ce5ec) contract in the Polygon network, and use it in my contract deployed on Mainnet. Is it possible to have two providers to interact with contracts in two different networks, all in the same script?

I'm using Hardhat for deploying and interacting with the smart contracts.